# How to tell android testrunner to test external.apk insted of generated app-debug.apk?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, build.gradle, android-testing

In my test project,inside java->androidTest(com.company.xyx.test) folder I have written all the android instrumentation tests to test external.apk(not app-debug.apk), I have a separate apk with same package name of test project(com.company.xyz), what I want is when I run the test it should install external.apk and androidTest.apk to run all the tests.

**Please some one tell me how to tell the test runner to run external apk or how to replace app-debug.apk from ~/output/apk/app-debug.apk to Externalapp.apk so that it should install the Externalapp.apk not app-debug**

Thanks in advance..

Here is my build.gradle of app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tri.rec"
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile files('src/androidTest/java/com/tri/re/libs/android-junit-report-1.5.8.jar')
compile files('src/androidTest/java/com/tri/re/libs/robotium-solo-5.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar')
compile files('src/androidTest/java/com/tri/re/libs/spoon-client-1.1.1.jar')
}
```

androidTest build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to    all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Please some tell me how to tell the test runner to run external apk or how to replace app-debug.apk from ~/output/apk/app-debug.apk to Externalapp.apk so that it should install the Externalapp.apk

Comment: Try to differentiate the sha1 of both the apks

Comment: @penta Thanks for your comment, but what I want is when I run the tests it should not test the application in which tests are written, I want it to test external.apk which has the same package name as test project, I hope you got my point. Like robotium recorder testing using apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

Using this [spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/) command you can do this

```
 java -jar C:\Users\Shivam\Downloads\spoon-runner-1.1.1-jar-with- dependencies.jar --apk 
 D:\Signedapks\external.apk  --test-apk
 C:\Users\Shivam\AndroidStudioProjects\TestingTool\app\build\outputs\apk\app-
debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk --sdk E:\sdk
```

external.apk must be signed with same keystore as debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk and package name must be same as external.apk's package name.